# What to do when C# Matrix is out of bound

Tags: c#, matrix

So I'm stuck with this...

[image: Value of C is out of Matrix bound]

I want to do a for loop to do a diagonal switch of my matrix values until the matrix come back to it's original position (A,B,C in the 1st row).

But I dont really know how to save C and put it back in the first column...

So far I have this code done.

```
    private Bitmap _imageBitmap;

    public Bitmap ImageBitmap
    {
        get { return this._imageBitmap; }
        set { this._imageBitmap = value; }
    }


    public int Height
    {
        get { return this._imageBitmap.Height; }
    }


    public int Width
    {
        get { return this._imageBitmap.Width; }
    }

    public Color this[int i, int j]
    {
        get { return this.ImageBitmap.GetPixel(i, j); }
        set { this.ImageBitmap.SetPixel(i, j, value); }
    }

    public BitmapMatricielle(Bitmap imageBitmap)
    {
        this.ImageBitmap = imageBitmap;
    }

    public void DecalageDiagonale()
    {
        for (int cptHeight = 0; cptHeight < this.Height; cptHeight++)
        {
            for (int cptWidth = 0; cptWidth < this.Width; cptWidth++)
            {
                int iFinal = this.Height + 1;
                int jFinal = this.Width + 1;
                Color tempo = this[cptWidth, cptHeight];
                this[iFinal, jFinal] = tempo;
                this[cptWidth, cptHeight] = this[iFinal, jFinal];
            }
        }
    }
```

Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: what is a diagonal switch? A transposition? I don't really get what your code is supposed to do from your explanations and your code snippet

Comment: I'm sorry that my post was unclear, basically what I want to achieve is to rotate all the value of my matrix in a diagonal way (diagonal to the button) and repeat the operation until the values in my matrix are like the original matrix.

Comment: What is the order, Down -> Right -> Up -> Left ?, The isn't really a rotation if it's not in a normal pattern, If it's just Down then Right, then Left... It's not Like requesting, always move all values right...